# How to update the Ubuntu 16.04 in command line while the network needs authentication

Tags: ubuntu, login

My Ubuntu 16.04 went to blue screen after the login page, so after googling the problem, I found that I should go to the virtual console by pressing the keyboard combination Ctrl+Shift+F1 and run `sudo apt update` in order to solve the blue screen.

The problem is that I'm at the university and I have to go through a login page in order to connect to the internet.

I have tested the curl command below:

```
curl --data "Username=xx&Password=xx&Login=Login" [url that your form submits]
```

but I can't update Ubuntu yet.

Comment: `apt-get update` only updates the package index DB. You need an `apt-get upgrade` to update your already installed packages with the new versions. Since this will pull the required files from the repo, it won't be easy to do without an internet connection... But you can get the .deb files using a working computer, import them to your PC with a USB key, and then install them with `dpkg -i package.deb`.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems downloading all the .deb packages takes a lot of time. Is there a way to download all?!

Comment: How many packages are you supposed to download? Maybe you should reconsider this method as a way to fix your problem. What broke? A configuration? Or files erased by mistake? if i's a configuration, `dpkg-reconfigure` could be enough.

Comment: You mean, `dpkg-reconfigure`?